# Installed .net 4.5.1 on developer machine now deployment iis has sprung memory leak / GC not running

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, memory-leaks, .net-4.5

So i recently got visual studio 2013 and .net 4.5.1 to use and i moved my .net 4.0 project to 2013 and recently compiled and deployed it on a server that only has .net 4.0 on it. I have two deployment machines that are synced with webdeployment agent service.

After i published and synced the servers from the 2013 project one of the servers is routinely running out of memory for one of its app pools. I inspect one of the processes with Process Explorer and it shows this. This process has been running for 6+ hours and was eating up 2.5gb of ram at the time.

[image: No Garbage collection occurring!]

I've done some searching and i can't discover why only one of my servers is presenting this issue. Are there any patches that were released to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated both servers with .net updates and the problem went away. Funny thing is none of the descriptions for them looked like anything relevant.